# 500 Internal Server Error returned from AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to test out API gateway and Lambda functions however I can't seem to get my API gateway to connect to the Lambda function.

I started by creating a lambda function with node.js.  I set an environment variable `NODE_ENV: production`.

Next I use API Gateway to create a REST API and configure a resource.  I configure as a proxy resource, set my resource name to employee-api, and finally set the resource path to {proxy+}.

After I create my resource I connect it to my lambda function and deploy.  Lastly I set Deployment Stage to [New Stage] and Stage Name to prod.

Now I zip a file containing my server code to import to my lambda.
package.json

```
{
  "name": "employee-management",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "deploy": "npm run clean && npm run build && aws lambda update-function-code --function-name employees --zip-file fileb://build.zip --publish",
    "clean": "rm build.zip",
    "build": "zip -r build.zip node_modules index.js app.js routes.js",
    "start": "TABLE='employees' node app-local",
    "dynamodb-local-run": "docker-compose up",
    "create-database": "aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://employee-table-model.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8080"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.828.0",
    "aws-serverless-express": "^3.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express')
const app = require('./app')
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)

exports.handler = (event, context) => { awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context) }
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')

const routes = require('./routes');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());

app.use('/', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

routes.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const express = require('express');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const IS_OFFLINE = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';


const router = express.Router();

router.get('/employees', (req, res) => {
    res.json(result)
});


module.exports = router;
```

I am able to successfully upload the zip folder. However, when I try to my API gateway endpoint `/employees` I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

I would really appreciate some guidance here.

Edit:  As requested I am attaching the logs.
Response Body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Internal Server Error</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Response Headers

```
{"access-control-allow-origin":"*","date":"Sun, 17 Jan 2021 23:19:50 GMT","content-length":"148","content-security-policy":"default-src 'none'","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","x-powered-by":"Express","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","connection":"close","X-Amzn-Trace-Id":"Root=1-6004c616-049f5587907c5f7d284b2b32;Sampled=0"}
```

Response Logs

```
Execution log for request 540fb10a-6f09-454e-9eaa-15b4f8426d35
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Starting execution for request: 540fb10a-6f09-454e-9eaa-15b4f8426d35
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /employees
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Method request path: {proxy=employees}
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Method request query string: {}
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Method request headers: {}
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Method request body before transformations: 
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:451162917588:function:employee/invocations
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=540fb10a-6f09-454e-9eaa-15b4f8426d35, Authorization=************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************aac4ac, X-Amz-Date=20210117T231950Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=fvixuu8pdb, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:451162917588:fvixuu8pdb/test-invoke-stage/GET/{proxy+}, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_fvixuu8pdb, X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHYaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCID6iyyWytqjpIbccEflk7s1qiVw9iKvWpe0LbT5pcyI7AiBe6r8TEMz4ATvlz6i0KFotp4YwcaW9CK9ZWZaahe5IyCq0AwhPEAAaDDM5MjIyMDU3NjY1MCIM8qvfeXj6wmlPGdUqKpEDV/ALuc4ecN/bWVzyjV7JWIbK3EPy+QRSHfwcCaMtD/RS7WSGIy94M6t/4PC0kF4ohRCRRfIaoleQy+r13pwItsib5tl6MIQh2W+92rxEC5WfrEiwkReW4pI6Ilgnc4GkhHb5yln53fACHZfIhL7i1guK6AKK6oGh [TRUNCATED]
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/{proxy+}","path":"/employees","httpMethod":"GET","headers":null,"multiValueHeaders":null,"queryStringParameters":null,"multiValueQueryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":{"proxy":"employees"},"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"resourceId":"klp4o9","resourcePath":"/{proxy+}","httpMethod":"GET","extendedRequestId":"ZUPjeE4_oAMF9iA=","requestTime":"17/Jan/2021:23:19:50 +0000","path":"/{proxy+}","accountId":"451162917588","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","stage":"test-invoke-stage","domainPrefix":"testPrefix","requestTimeEpoch":1610925590175,"requestId":"540fb10a-6f09-454e-9eaa-15b4f8426d35","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"cognitoIdentityId":null,"apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","principalOrgId":null,"cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"userArn":"arn:aws:iam::451162917588:root","apiKeyId":"test-invoke-api-key-id","userAgent":"aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.901 Linux/4.9.230-0.1.ac.223.84.332.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.275-b01 java/1.8 [TRUNCATED]
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Sending request to https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:451162917588:function:employee/invocations
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 173 ms
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Sun, 17 Jan 2021 23:19:50 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=492, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=63f9de04-ab75-49dc-b80b-ce3db518c421, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-6004c616-049f5587907c5f7d284b2b32;sampled=0}
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":500,"body":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Internal Server Error</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n","headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","access-control-allow-origin":"*","content-security-policy":"default-src 'none'","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","content-length":"148","date":"Sun, 17 Jan 2021 23:19:50 GMT","connection":"close"},"isBase64Encoded":false}
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Method response body after transformations: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Internal Server Error</pre>
</body>
</html>

Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Method response headers: {x-powered-by=Express, access-control-allow-origin=*, content-security-policy=default-src 'none', x-content-type-options=nosniff, content-type=text/html; charset=utf-8, content-length=148, date=Sun, 17 Jan 2021 23:19:50 GMT, connection=close, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-6004c616-049f5587907c5f7d284b2b32;Sampled=0}
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Successfully completed execution
Sun Jan 17 23:19:50 UTC 2021 : Method completed with status: 500
```

Comment: Check the logs. Share those logs here. 500 means the internel server error. That is your code has broken most probably.

Comment: I just updated my question with the logs.

Comment: Your lambda logs in CloudWatch logs. If lambda fails, the reason why it happens will be there.

Comment: hmm I cant seem to find any logs in CloudWatch

Comment: How did you connect your API to lambda? Is it proxy integration? Does your lambda even execute from API?

Comment: Yes it is proxy integration. I am not positive the lambda is being executed, however in the monitoring tab for my lambda function I can see some data in the graphs.

Comment: You can check `invocations` metric.

Comment: Yes there are invocations.  But no logs

Comment: Does you function have basic execution permissions which contain CloudWatch Logs permissions? Also if you invoke your function manually, using AWS Lambda console with `Test` button, there are also no logs?

Comment: The role I am using has `AmazonDMSCloudWatchLogsRole` attached to it but I still don't seem to be logging anything.  I have used the test feature but I get a 404 error.